# Combining simple schema errors

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

I'm trying to combine fields using simple schema. It works for `Schema.UserProfile` however it doesn't work for `Schema.accountStatus`.

If I try and populate the field when I create a new account it errors. Any thoughts on why, would really help, thanks?

Path: `schemas.js`

```
Schema = {};

Schema.accountStatus = new SimpleSchema({
    isUserAccountActive: {
        type: Boolean,
        optional: true
    },
    startDate: {
        type: Date,
        optional: true
    },
    endDate: {
        type: Date,
        optional: true
    }
});

Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        optional: false
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
});

Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    profile: {
        type: Schema.UserProfile,
        optional: true
    },
    // Make sure this services field is in your schema if you're using any of the accounts packages
    services: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    },
    accountStatus: {
        type: Schema.accountStatus,
        optional: true

    },
    // In order to avoid an 'Exception in setInterval callback' from Meteor
    heartbeat: {
        type: Date,
        optional: true
    }
});

Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);
```

Path: `startup.js`

```
Meteor.startup(function () {

  console.log('Running server startup code...');

  Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
    if (options.profile && options.profile.roles) {
      //include the user profile
      Roles.setRolesOnUserObj(user, options.profile.roles);
    }

    if (options.profile) {
      // include the user profile
      user.profile = options.profile;
    }

    // other user object changes...
    // ...
    user.isUserAccountActive = false;


    return user;
  });

});
```

Comment: What's the error message and what's the object that you're inserting look like?

Comment: The error message is "Internal server error". I'm trying to insert 'user.isUserAccountActive = false' into the database.

Comment: I've cut out the boilerplate code. Am I combining the schemas correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see now: `isUserAccountActive` is a sub-key of `accountStatus`. Change:

```
user.isUserAccountActive = false;
```

to

```
user.accountStatus = { isUserAccountActive: false };
```

Not clear why that should yield a server error though, perhaps it's because you're doing this update on the server side.

Comment: Nope that didn't work. I'm still getting the server error. In my console I'm getting this error: 'Exception while invoking method 'ATCreateUserServer' TypeError: Cannot set property 'isUserAccountActive' of undefined
I20160204-19:35:42.568(11)?     at AccountsServer._onCreateUserHook (server/startup.js:18:43)'

Comment: such a legend! Thanks